# Cross-compiling ImageMagick on ARM

Tags: libraries, cross-compilation

The following is for ImageMagick cross compiled on ARM, I have successfully cross compiled it but while using the convert binary on cross environment it gives following error:

```
[root@FriendlyARM bin]# convert
convert: error while loading shared libraries: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[root@FriendlyARM bin]# ldd convert
        libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.8 (0x40113000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x4014f000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x40204000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x40009000)
        libgomp.so.1 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x40277000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x40057000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x4019d000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x402e9000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x400ce000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x400ed000)
```

Please help me getting these libraries dependencies resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `libgomp` on your ARM system. If you give more detail on your target (distribution in particular) I can add more detail to my answer...

Comment: My target is FriendlyARM 6410. Can you provide the link to download the library libgomp ??

Comment: Looking at it briefly I don't think you'll find `libgomp` pre-compiled specifically for FriendlyARM; but since you cross-compiled ImageMagick, you should have the appropriate ARM `libgomp.so.1` file on the system you used to cross-compile.